# Android Basic Tutorial Adding the Action Bar , error: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

Hi I am new to Android Programming and currently am learning the tutorial from this site:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

The error message i received in my MainActivity.java is
R cannnot be resolved to a variable

code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;

    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

 }
```

The error occurs at the following lines:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

Please help

Comment: try after cleaning Project and then press `CTRL+SHIFT+O` to import you own project `R` file instead of `android.R`

Comment: Hi I tried that but it still does not work

Comment: Do you have your R.java file under the Java Generated Folder?

Comment: Hi, 
no  I don't have R.java file under the gen folder

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur due to some error in your resources. Please check your layouts and also the naming conventions of the images and other media which you have used in your project. In my case I had an error in a layout file and after fixing it R.java got created in the gen folder of my project. Please go through all your layout files.

Answer (score 0):

try to add:
import com.example.R;

or,
Ctrl + Shift + O (in Windows with Eclipse)

finally,
try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your import com.example.R line is missing.  That infers that you have a build error with one of your resources.  If you're using eclipse, expand the res folder and keep expanding till you find the file with the error flag.  Then, see if you can identify and fix the error.

Comment: Does com.example.R exist?  If not, there is an error.  I've noticed, in eclipse, it doesn't always put up a flag.  But in the "problems" pane, it will show an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my kubuntu linux 64 bit installation.
I solved installing 32 bit library ia32-libs (sudo apt-get install ia32-libs).
Don't know is 64 bit windows has same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, One of many in Google My first app tutorial.

it looks like you need check your XML folder layout to induce a file called activity_main.xml if its not that then it wont work.